# Select2 autocomplete doesn't work properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have the below form :

```
<form id="form-name" class="form-male" method="POST" action="/submit">
         <div class="form-select">
             <select name="name" class="select2-menu">
                <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">ΟΝΟΜΑ</option>
                <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
                <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    <button type="submit" class="cta cta-primary btn btn-default"><img src="img/submit.png" class="img-center img-responsive" /></button>
</form>

<script src="js/select2.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('select').select2({
                // minimumInputLength: 1,
                casesensitive: false,
    //            minimumResultsForSearch: -1
            });
</script>
```

The above example when i type "A" it stops showing "Alaska" and it shows only "Alabama". It continues to show "Alabama" until the phrase "Ala". When phrase "Alab" is written, it doesn't show any results.

Any ideas?

Comment: Unable to replicate that behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/y930ca9n/.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You are right - it does work but i can't understand why in my .html . I've tried replacing my .js and .css with the one the select2 provides through their external servers but nothing changed. I am trying to find if any code has any conflict but can't find something..

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for the help found the answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the style.css